# Mongoid many-to-many with versioning

Tags: ruby-on-rails, version-control, mongodb, associations, mongoid

Assume, that a user wants to create a set consisting of items created by other users. Mongoid Document for item has versioning, and the user who creates the set might not enjoy changes the item authors do with the items of the set. Therefore I would like the set document to refer to specific versions of items, allowing the set author to update item references if wanted. I am planning adding an array of item version numbers to the set document, and some methods for getting set items of certain version and for updating the item versions. Do you find this approach reasonable? How would you solve this problem?

```
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paranoia
  include Mongoid::Versioning
  field :title, type: String
  has_and_belongs_to_many :item_sets
end

class ItemSet
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :item_versions, type: Array
  has_and_belongs_to_many :items
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved problems like this by creating a model in the "middle" like "ItemReference"
MongoDB is a document store and not a relational database, so it is legitimate to store duplicate information when necessary. MongoDB has the ability to store embedded documents, so we're gonna use this great feature.

The ItemReference holds all crucial information about the Item which is needed for creating a view. This reduces the queries on the view side but in increases the queries on the insert/update side.

The thing is that you need a "composite primary key" that consists of the `item_id` and the version number.

Let's talk code:

**The Item Model:**

```
class Item
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Paranoia
  include Mongoid::Versioning

  field :title, :type => String

  # create a reference
  def to_reference
    # create new reference, containing all crucial attributes for displaying
    ItemReference.new(  
      :item_id => self._parent.nil? ? self.id : self._parent.id,
      :version => self.version, 
      :title => self.title
    )
  end

  # get a certain version of this item
  def get_version(version_number)
    return self if version_number == self.version
    self.versions.where(:version => version_number).first
  end

end
```

**The ItemSet Model**

```
class ItemSet
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, :type => String

  embeds_many :item_references
end
```

**The ItemReference Model**

```
class ItemReference 
  include Mongoid::Document
  embedded_in :item_sets  

  field :title, :type => String

  # this points to the newest version
  belongs_to :item

  # get the original version
  def original
    self.item.get_version(self.version)
  end

  # update this reference to a certain version
  def update_to!(new_version)
    new_version     = self.item.get_version(new_version)
    if new_version.present?
      # copy attribute, except id
      self.attributes = new_version.to_reference.attributes.reject{|(k,v)| k == "_id"} 
      self.save  
    else
      # version not found
      false
    end
  end

  # update to the newest version
  def update_to_head!
    self.update_to!(self.item.version)
  end
end
```

This combination allows you to create sets holding Items with different versions, and you can update certain ItemReferences in the set to a specific version.

Here's an example:

```
first         = Item.create(:title => 'Item 1')
first.title   = 'Item 1.1'
first.save

myset         = ItemSet.create(:title => 'My Set')
myset.item_references << first.to_reference
myset.save

first.title   = 'Item 1.2'
first.save

p myset.item_references.first.title # prints Item 1.1
p myset.item_references.first.update_to_head! 
p myset.item_references.first.title # prints Item 1.2
p myset.item_references.first.update_to!(1)
p myset.item_references.first.title # prints Item 1
```